# Richard Stallman compares Linux with Windows

Tags: linux, windows, gnu

I'm posting this here, because I really don't know any other place that could answer this. I'm curious about switching to Linux. I'm referring to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kfli_e923o4

He discusses three points.

1. Designed around being able to have multiple users at the same time and to be isolated from each other.
2. *"Microsoft makes a [bad] decision where they run programs that arrive in files that you just happen to have on your computer"*
3. Market-share

My question is can anyone explain his second point to me?

Comment: Maybe he is referring to the fact that MS-Windows sets the execute permission on every file. Therefore a user can easily execute a file that they downloaded from a dodgy website. On Unix systems we don't teach about how to make a file executable, until we have taught about the danger of random files. It also stops random execution.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that Stallman is making the point that Linux is open source and therefor a Linux user can check the source code before he compiles the code and then run it.
Further more if you have the time and skill you can create your personal Linux distribution and you would be in total control of your system.

On Windows the users have no access to the source code and they just have to accept binary programs without the opportunity to check what a program is really doing. On a basic Windows installation there are 16GB (maybe less, maybe more) of installed programs and all the decision for these 16 GB are made by Microsoft for you.

With Linux you can get the free choice on what you install while on Windows you Microsoft make the choice for you.

All that I have said is true when you would build your Linux from scratch, but the thing is very few people do that, because it is very comfortable if someone makes difficult decisions for you.
Most people install a Ubuntu, Fedora or a SUSE since it is easy and fast to install and all these distributions need to make decisions for you to make it easy and fast to install.

I should add that with Windows and with Linux the decisions that are made by the creators of the system are not written in stone and you can always change the system to your liking, but i found it much easier with open source systems.

In the end it is a question of trust. Do you trust Microsoft to do a good job or do you trust Canonical(Ubuntu) or Red Hat (Fedora) and if you can only trust yourself then you have to build it all by yourself.

Comment: Of course, [you can't necessarily even trust yourself](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TheKenThompsonHack) (or at least your compiler), even if you build it from source code.

Comment: mhhh maybe if you write one but then there is the cpu :D

Answer (score 1):

He is referring to the concept of distributions and package managers.

Linux comes in distributions, which means

- you chose a limited set of sources from where you get your software and
- there is a piece of software, which installs it and
- the software has to follow certain rules to even be installable (e.g. a Debian package).

With Windows you get software in the form of an executable you download from arbitrary locations. This is a lot easier to exploit when trying to put malicious software on a remote computer, because its normal with Windows to download a programm from a site you seem to like and execute it.

With Linux you usually install software from your predefined sources. So malicious software would first have to make its way into such a location and remain hidden all the time. This is a lot harder to pull off.